# Disable purging of unused CSS in svelte

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, svelte-component

is there a way to tell svelte to not remove my unused styles?

I'm working with webcomponents and sub-components aren't styled if svelte purges the unused selectors.
I hope there is a setting i can configure in rollup?

Comment: Just use the [:global() modifier](https://svelte.dev/docs#style) to declare global styles. They won't get purged